# Assigning partner values for paired rows in SPSS

Tags: syntax, spss

Imagine a dataset with pairs of participants ("Couple" 1-10), each of whom have a unique identifier ("Person" 1 or 2). Each of these individuals within a pair have a unique value on some variable, call it "Actor". I want to write a script that takes the "Actor" value for the individual and puts it into a new variable for the other individual in the pair called "Partner." In this way, each Person (row) would have a value for themselves ("Actor") and a value of their partner ("Partner").

The method that I've attempted involves restructuring:

```
SORT CASES BY Couple.
CASESTOVARS
  /ID=Couple
  /GROUPBY=VARIABLE.

COMPUTE Partner.1=Actor.2.
COMPUTE Partner.2=Actor.1.
EXECUTE.

VARSTOCASES
  /MAKE Person FROM Person.1 Person.2
  /MAKE Actor FROM Actor.1 Actor.2
  /MAKE Partner FROM Partner.1 Partner.2
  /INDEX=Index1(2) 
  /KEEP=Couple 
  /NULL=KEEP.
```

Now this works perfectly for the small, hypothetical dataset that I've created. However, I'd like the script to be able to handle more variables without the user having to manually type in more /MAKE commands.

Something like this?

```
for i in varlist[var=all]
do
VARSTOCASES
/MAKE i FROM i.1 i.2
/INDEX=Index1(2).
```

But that's not valid SPSS code. Anyone know how I might rig this up?

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the specific problem you're having. "Advanced SPSS syntax" is going to be pretty meaningless in a search result for the person searching this site in the future to help with a problem they're having. Your question being about SPSS is known from the tags, as is that it's related to syntax. This leaves the only word in your title "Advanced", which does nothing to tell anyone what the question concerns. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
SORT CASES BY couple (A) Person (A).
IF (couple = LAG(couple)) partner = LAG(actor).

SORT CASES BY couple (A) Person (D).
IF (couple = LAG(couple)) partner = LAG(actor).
```

**Explanation:** First you sort your data set in a way, that every actor is followed by it's partner. Then you can use the LAG-function to copy the actor's id (from the upper row) into the partner's (second row) partner variable. Since there is no Follower-like function in SPSS (I'm really missing it) you can't copy a value from the second row into the first one directly. You have to sort the person variable in a descending order first.

Comment: Fantastic, very clever. It looks like this works, but only after running the syntax two times. Is there a way to make it work after a single pass? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You probably need to add the EXECUTE command after the whole procedure. Otherwise the second IF-Statement would stay pending until you run a command which causes execution of pending commands. That was in your case probably the first SORT CASES command when you ran the syntax a second time.